# Does a QToolBox own its items?

Tags: qt

When a widget is added to a QToolBox, will the ownership of the widget be transfered to the QToolBox? Phrased differently: Will it become the new parent and destroy the widget when itself is destroyed)?

Comment: It's easy to check. After you add the item, see who's the parent. More importantly, the parent could be an internal widget within `QToolBox`. So what you really want to do is add the item, then iterate QToolBox's descendant tree, and check if your widget comes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you construct the widget using `new QWidget(pointer_to_toolbox);` or something similar the toolbox will take ownership of the widget.

The documentation of [addItem()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbox.html#addItem) doesn't say anything about ownership, so I would bet that the toolbox doesn't take ownership of any widget passed to `addItem()`

Answer (score 3):

From what I can gather from the qt source code the toolbox does not take ownership of the item. Here is a snippet of `insertItem` function from src/gui/qtoolbox.cpp:

```
int QToolBox::insertItem(int index, QWidget *widget, const QIcon &icon, const QString &text)
{
    if (!widget)
        return -1;

    Q_D(QToolBox);
    connect(widget, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), this,SLOT(_q_widgetDestroyed(QObject*)));

    QToolBoxPrivate::Page c;
    c.widget = widget;

    ...
 }
```

As one can see from the code the `QToolBox` assigns a pointer to the `widget` parameter to its own private variable. And when the widget is destroyed the `QToolBox` is notified.

P.S. I have checked out qt source from git. and I cannot find `addItem` implementation in `qtoolbox.cpp`. There are comments about it but there is only declaration of it in `qtoolbox.h` . hmm....

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the organisation of your code. You can design your code in way that it enable reuse of the objects associated with qtoolbox, you have to be more specific.

Comment: There is nothing about my code here. I need to know the behaviour of QToolBox so I can organize my code not to leak, segfault or have object tree circles.

Comment: QT as it's based on C++ is not different than any  OOP defined objects. If you assign an object members dynamically it will loose connection to its parent when this object is deleted(this also depends whether you assign  as a class member or trough aggregation). This also gives you the chance to pass it by value, in that case the problem is the QT's fancy code generator(especially its signal and slot mechanism), passing by value is not always compatible with QT's internal design.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand the issue. If something that derives from `QObject` (call it object O) is said `to take ownership of an object A` A is being made a child of O. O will delete all it's children as soon as its destructor is called. Qt is something not entirely clear when something takes ownership of something else and my question is about on such specific case, where it would be sensible to take ownership of something, but apparently is not done. Nothing with about the `moc` or signals and slots here.